# Why does floating an input element change its height?

Tags: css, css-float, height

Basically I would like a span and a input element to take up the same amount of vertical space, so as to align the text in the two boxes properly. I can achieve this quite easily when not floating the elements. But as soon as I add a float property, some extra pixels are added to the input element's height. And I cannot for the life of me understand why that is.

And how do I fix it?

This problem exists on Safari on iOS 6 and Chrome on the desktop. Also happens in Firefox, but the effects are somewhat different.

I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oligofren/cYaa2/3/) that shows my problem.

```
<input class='float' value="some text" id='input2'/>
<span class='float' id='text2'>some text</span><br />

input, span {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

input {
    text-align: right;
}

.float {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Isn't floating the span actually removing from it's height? Everything is 17 but the floated span is 15.

Comment: True! Well observed! Changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. It seems floating the input is giving it a 2px margin, which you can easily remove. If you do that and remove the line-height attribute, everything seems to line up on both counts.

http://jsfiddle.net/cYaa2/4/

```
input, span {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

input {
    text-align: right;
}

.float {
    float: right;
}

input.float {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm ... I am awarding you the answer, since you actually answered what I asked. Too bad that what I was asking wasn't what I wanted answered :p The original problem was showing on iPhone, and I tried replicating it by the above snippet. But alas, the two were not the same, it turned out. I'll try a bit harder next time to create an equivalent snippet that _actually_, not just seemingly, replicates the problem.

Comment: Haha, sorry! If you ask a new question I'll do my best to answer it, but I'm not as skilled with iPhone stuff.